# PHP preg_match - regex is unexpectedly greedy

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, backreference

I'm trying to match a series of characters in a string of spaced-out letters. Here's a few examples:

- " a b c d e "
- " a c c d e "
- " b e "
- " b c e "
- " e f g "

I want it to match anything with " e ", but I also want two results for the backreferences. If " b" is found, it should be the first backreference and the second should be anything between " b" and " e ". If there's no " b", it doesn't much matter what the second backreference is. Here's my test code:

```
$regex = "( b)?( .*)?? e ";

preg_match("/{$regex}/", " a b c d e ", $matches);
```

This returns $matches of "" (nothing) and " a b c d ". However, it works how I want it to if I remove the space at the front:

```
preg_match("/{$regex}/", "a b c d e ", $matches);
```

This returns $matches of " b" and " c d". Bingo! But I need that initial space in the haystack string. I thought the ( b)? would be greedy because of the ? at the end, and expected the ( .*)?? to be lazy. But it's preferring the lazy ( .*)?? over it.

It almost seems that the first priority of the regex is to match from the beginning of the string, and only THEN consider greediness/laziness. Is this true?

Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQ2gO1/3).

In the real, non-simplified regex, there can be multiple ( b)? strings, and each are actually complex regexes dozens of characters long, so negation isn't going to be feasible in the ( .*)??.

What I'm really trying to get at is this - I want both the first and second group to be optional. I want the first group to be greedy, and the second group to be ungreedy. Currently the second group is overriding the first because it can match earlier in the string.

Is there a way to modify the regex to accomplish what I need?

Comment: Try `(\sb)(.*)e`. Check [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQ2gO1/1)

Comment: That works if we know there is a "b", but it might not be in there. I'll update the question with more details.

Comment: @Bonjiro What is your expected match for `a a c c e f `?

Comment: @Maus - without a "b" in there, the first backreference would be empty and the second wouldn't matter, though I suppose empty would be ideal for that one, too.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex:

```
( b)?((?:(?!b).)*)? e
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kY9bG4/5)

The point is that the second group cannot match `b`, or it will always "override" the first optional group.

Comment: Thanks, but if that first space is obligatory, it won't match " e " if there's no "b" in the series. I changed the regex a little up above, and added a demo link with examples to clarify.

Comment: @Bonjiro: I modified my answer. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, that works in the simplified version I posted here. 

The issue remaining is that in the real regex, "b" is a regex that's about 40 characters long. It wouldn't work (and be a real mess) to copy that into the [^b]. I was hoping there would be a way to tune the greediness to get an answer. 

Do you know why the regex is preferring to match from the start of the string, regardless of the greediness of the items within?

Comment: You confuse greediness with optional groups. When a group is optional, and the next group can match the same characters and it is not optional, the characters will go to the second group. I updated the regex for a variable-length `b`.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. In the real (non-simplified) regex, there can be several long "( b)" searches before the ( .*)??. Negation classes in the ( .*)?? are going to be too long and complex in the real regex. What I'm really trying to get at is this - I want both the first and second group to be optional. I want the first group to be greedy, and the second group to be ungreedy.

Comment: I think you should post the real-life examples.